# How do I add UEFI Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS legacy boot grub?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

Pretty self-explanatory. I recently dual booted my system and I am able to choose which to boot into at bios. I would like to be able to choose which OS to boot into through the ubuntu grub, but it does not detect Windows 10. I have tried making a custom grub boot option by adding the correct partition and pasting something like  `search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root $my uuid$
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi`. It returns with `bootmgfw.efi not found`. Windows and Ubuntu boot correctly, but Windows does not appear in grub.

Comment: Would be easier have both match bios type.  Win 10 should be able to install in legacy, as I imagine you have had Ubuntu for some time and do not wish to reinstall.  Windows installed in legacy will tend to replace grub upon install and during updates.

Comment: If both are booting well by bios, be happy since right now that is the easiest.  Next easiest is to reinstall one or both of them to match.

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  But UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. Once you start booting in one mode, you cannot switch, or grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode. You can continue to dual boot from UEFI or reinstall on of the systems to boot in the other mode if not the same.

Comment: I was able to install the boot-repair iso on a flash drive and it was able to switch the boot mode of my Ubuntu installation to UEFI. This [Ubuntu guide to switching to UEFI booting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_UEFI_mode) was quite helpful and solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. The [disk partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_table) is either MBR (aka Legacy) or GPT (for use with UEFI).

Answer (score 0):

### Booting Ubuntu and Windows using grub

It sounds to me like you have Ubuntu and Windows on separate disks.

I have done a lot of googling and asked a similar question without getting an answer. [Chainload Windows 10 1909 UEFI on one disk using BIOS grub on other disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196972/chainload-windows-10-1909-uefi-on-one-disk-using-bios-grub-on-other-disk)

I created a new Ubuntu disk using UEFI and installed it next to the Windows disk. I then ran `sudo update grub` and now both the Linux disk and the Windows now boot from grub.