# How to install windows on a separate hard drive

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows

So I am looking to dual boot. I currently have ubuntu installed on my SSD. I bought a new SSD that I would like to install windows 10 on for gaming. How do I go about installing windows without messing up my ubuntu installation?

Comment: Pull your Ubuntu drive out, install Windows on the new drive, then install the Ubuntu drive back in then update the GRUB from Ubuntu so it sees the new Windows installation.

Comment: @Terrance: I agree, however updating GRUB to add the Windows installation only works if both OS are either BIOS or both UEFI. GRUB on BIOS Ubuntu will not boot UEFI Windows.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Hopefully OP will install them both the same way.  Direct your comment to OP and not me.  I already understand that.

Comment: @Terrance The OP is a new contributor, why would you expect him to install both the same way?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Windows 10 automatically chooses based on what BIOS is set to.  Version older than Windows 8 will not boot to systems running UEFI.  I already fought with this one on my son's new motherboard as I was going to upgrade for Key purposes like I have done in the past.  Windows 7 wouldn't even boot to the DVD without the system being in Legacy mode.  Chances are, it is already set to UEFI and OP should be fine.

Comment: @Terrance: On the other hand Ubuntu is happy to install to BIOS, some Ubuntu Live USB installer tools are BIOS only, (YUMI), Windows 10 prefers installing as UEFI mode. I recently spent days trying to get my BIOS mode Ubuntu to add my UEFI Win 10 install to my GRUB menu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196972/chainload-windows-10-1909-uefi-on-one-disk-using-bios-grub-on-other-disk I am only suggesting that it might save the OP some time if you mention this.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, Windows should not ruin your bootloader if it's installed on a different drive. That being said, Windows is Windows, and we really don't ever know what it's going to do. So I would do what was suggested in the comments: remove your Ubuntu drive, install Windows in the new drive, then put the Ubuntu drive back, and make sure you boot into Ubuntu (may have to change boot order in your BIOS/UEFI settings). One in Ubuntu, update your GRUB configuration so Windows shows up in the list. Then when you boot, your Ubuntu drive will load GRUB, which you can then choose to boot Windows if you'd like.

Comment: If Windows is installed in UEFI mode, Ubuntu must also be installed in UEFI mode for it's GRUB bootloader to boot Windows.